# Cómo pasar a la función string.match(line,pattern) el contenido de una variable en el patrón a buscar pattern

Tags: string, regex, lua

Necesito hacer un programa que, dado un string de entrada, lo busque en la primera columna de un fichero con múltiples filas que tienen 2 datos en cada fila separado por una coma y saque como resultado el string que hay en la segunda posición de la fila donde está el string de entrada. El siguiente sería un ejemplo de fichero llamado Datos.txt:
Dato1old,Dato1new
Dato2old,Dato2new
Dato3old,Dato3new

Si nos pasaran como string de entrada DAto2old, el programa debería devolver como resultado Dato2new.

EL objetivo es abrir el fichero, buscar un string de entrada que estará en la primera columna y conseguir sacar en la variable de salida el dato que hay en esa fila tras la coma, es decir, si pasan al programa Dato2old, deberá conseguir asignar a una variable el contenido Dato2new.

La parte de abrir el fichero la tengo resuelta de la siguiente manera:

```
local open = io.open
local function read_file(path)
local file = open(path, "rb") -- r read mode and b binary mode
if not file then return nil end
local content = file:read "*a" -- *a or *all reads the whole file
file:close()
return content
end
end
end

local fileContent = read_file("Datos.txt");
```

Una vez tengo abierto el fichero, necesito conseguir el string tras la coma de la línea donde está el string pasado.
Esta parte la estoy intentando resolver de la siguiente manera:
function getmatches(text)
for line in string.gmatch(text, "[^\r\n]+") do
m = string.match(line,"Dato2old,([^,]+)")
if m ~= nil then
print(m)
end
end
end

A esta función la llamo tal que:
getmatches(fileContent) y consigo sacar el resultado Dato2new.

EL problema es que tengo el string a buscar hardcodeado en la instrucción y necesito que eso sea un valor de una variable que se pase al llamar a la función tal que la llamada fuera:
valorsalida=getmatches (filecontent,patterntosearch)
donde:
filecontent: sea el fichero a abrir
patterntosearch: sea al patrón a buscar en la primera conlumna (por ejemplo Dato2old)
valorsalida: el valor que hay al lado de Dato2old, que debería ser Dato2new.

La instrucción que uso es:
m = string.match(line,"Dato2old,([^,]+)")

Consigo asignar a la variable m el dato que necesito pero para ello debo poner el texto de la primera columna en la instrucción lo cual sólo funciona en el caso que el string a buscar sea Dato2old. Lo que necesitaría es poder poner en lugar del Dato2old, el valor de la variable que pasan al llamar a la función como patrón a buscar es decir, que la llamada fuera algo parecido a:

valorsalida=getmatches (filecontent,patterntosearch)

Y la función fuera:
function getmatches(text,pattern)
for line in string.gmatch(text, "[^\r\n]+") do
m = string.match(line,"**Valor_de_pattern**,([^,]+)")
if m ~= nil then
print(m)
end
end
end

No sé como construir la instrucción_
m = string.match(line,"**Valor_de_pattern**,([^,]+)")

Espero haberme explicado.
Muchas gracias por adelantado.